# How do I add names only in the Name column of the table?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I'm creating a dog top trumps style game using tkinter and need it too display names only in the Name column but it instead spreads the names across all columns

```
labelText.set("These are your cards")
tree = ttk.Treeview(root,columns=("Name","Exercise","Intelligence","Friendliness","Drool"))
tree["show"]= "headings"
namecol = tree.heading("Name", text="Name")
tree.heading("Exercise", text="Exercise")
tree.heading("Intelligence", text="Intelligence")
tree.heading("Friendliness", text="Friendliness")
tree.heading("Drool", text="Drool")

tree.grid(row=6,column=0,columnspan=5)

lbl = tkinter.Label(root, text="Your Cards")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=5, columnspan=5)


#creates a list with each dog in it
dogs = []

with open("dogs.txt", "rt") as in_file:
    for dog in in_file:
        dogs.append(dog)


for value in dogs:
    tree.insert("", "0", value=dogs)
```

I end with it displaying the text file over all columns instead of to the name column, instead of it only displaying in names

Comment: `tree.insert("", "0", value=dogs)` should be `tree.insert("", "0", value=value)`

Answer (score 1):

```
for value in dogs:
    tree.insert("", "0", value=dogs)
```

To

```
for value in dogs:
    tree.insert("", "0", value=value)
```

Comment: tried that but it only displays first names instead of full